# Is there a random number generator which can skip/drop N draws in O(1)?

Tags: random

Is there any (non-cryptographic) pseudo random number generator that can skip/drop N draws in O(1), or maybe O(log N) but smaller than O(N).

---

Especially for parallel applications it would be of advantage to have a generator of the above type. Image you want to generate an array of random numbers. One could write a parallel program for this task and seed the random number generator for each thread independently. However, the numbers in the array would then not be the same as for the sequential case (except for the first half maybe).

If a random number generator of the above type would exist, the first thread could seed with the seed used for the sequential implementation. The second thread could also seed with this seed and then drop/skip N/2 samples which are generated by the first thread. The output array would then be identical to the serial case (easy testing) but still generated in less time.
Below is some pseudo code.

```c
#define _POSIX_C_SOURCE 1
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <omp.h>

void rand_r_skip(unsigned int *p_seed, int N)
{
    /* Stupid O(N) Implementation */
    for (int i = 0; i < N; i++)
    {
        rand_r(p_seed);
    }
}

int main()
{
    int N = 1000000;
    unsigned int seed = 1234;
    int *arr = (int *)malloc(sizeof(int) * N);

#pragma omp parallel firstprivate(N, seed, arr) num_threads(2)
    {
        if (omp_get_thread_num() == 1)
        {
            // skip the samples, obviously doesn't exist
            rand_r_skip(&seed, N / 2);
        }
#pragma omp for schedule(static)
        for (int i = 0; i < N; i++)
        {
            arr[i] = rand_r(&seed);
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Thank you all very much for your help. I do know that there might be a proof that such a generator cannot exist and be "pseudo-random" at the same time. I am very grateful for any hints on where to find further information.

Comment: Obvious candidate would be any symmetric crypto cipher in counter mode.

Comment: @ChrisDodd: yep, and it would be O(1) to skip. Of course generation is comparatively expensive unless you trim the cipher down to only a few rounds.

Comment: Thank you for your comments.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sure. [Linear Conguential Generator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_congruential_generator) and its descendants could skip generation of `N` numbers in `O(log(N))` time. It is based on paper of F.Brown, [link](https://laws.lanl.gov/vhosts/mcnp.lanl.gov/pdf_files/anl-rn-arb-stride.pdf).

[Here](https://github.com/Kri-Ol/LCG-PLE63/) is an implementation of the idea, C++11.

Comment: Thank you for the quick reply.

Comment: @LukasKoestler you're welcome. Just remember, that LCG considered to be not a high quality RNG. But LCG based RNGs with better quality - PCG, I believe - share this O(log(N)) ability to jump ahead. http://www.pcg-random.org/

Answer (score 2):

As kindly indicated by Severin Pappadeux, the `C`, `C++` and `Haskell` implementations of a [PCG variant developed by M.E. O'Neill](http://www.pcg-random.org/) provides an interface to such **jump-ahead**/**jump-back** functionality: [herein](http://www.pcg-random.org/useful-features.html#jump-ahead-and-jump-back).

Function names are: `advance` and `backstep`, which were briefly documented [hereat](http://www.pcg-random.org/using-pcg-cpp.html#void-advance-state-type-delta) and [hereat](http://www.pcg-random.org/using-pcg-cpp.html#void-backstep-state-type-delta), respectively

Quoting from the webpage (accessed at the time of writing):

> ... a random number generator is like a book that lists page after page of statistically random numbers. The seed gives us a starting point, but sometimes it is useful to be able to move forward or backwards in the sequence, and to be able to do so efficiently.
>
> The C++ implementation of the PCG generation scheme provides advance to efficiently jump forwards and backstep to efficiently jump backwards.

Answer (score 0):

Chris Dodd wrote the following:

> Obvious candidate would be any symmetric crypto cipher in counter mode.